# Disable the analytics cookies, but keep the statistics

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

I just want to know if it is possible to disable the cookies set by analytics without disabling the whole service ?

Thanks

Comment: I highly doubt it. Try reading [the docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a solution which only sends a pixel request to the Google Analytics servers and never execute the javascript. Your reports would still be populated for pageviews, but it'd be severely limited.